# Check if a given list is a sublist of a larger list

Tags: python, loops, boolean-logic

```
def sublist(slist, blist):
    m = 0
    is_a_sublist = False
    for n in range(0, len(blist)):
     while (n < len(blist) and m < len(blist)) and is_a_sublist == False:
            spliced_list = blist[n:m]
            if spliced_list == slist:
                is_a_sublist = True
            else:
                m += 1

    return is_a_sublist

def main():
    test_list = ["a",9,1,3.14,2]
    original_list = ["a",1,"a",9,1,3.14,2]

    is_a_sublist = sublist(test_list,original_list)

    if is_a_sublist == True:
        print("It is a sublist!")
    else:
        print("It ain't a sublist!")


main()
```

The code I wrote above is to check if a given list is a "sublist" of a larger list. So, if a large list is [3,3,10,4,9], and the given list is [3,10,4], then it is a sublist so it must return True. But what's wrong with my code? When I run it, output is "It ain't a sublist" even though it is (function returns False). I only want to use loops, no built-in functions.

Comment: Most answers there are using complicated functions, just wanted to rely on loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's erroroneous for your code to have a for loop followed by a while loop.  Only for loop is needed to loop over blist.

So this is code is in error:

```
for n in range(0, len(blist)):
     while (n < len(blist) and m < len(blist)) and is_a_sublist == False:
```

**Simplified Code**

By simplyfying looping, removing superfluous variables and steps, your code can be simplified to the following:

```
def sublist(slist, blist):
  for n in range(len(blist)-len(slist)+1):
    if slist == blist[n:n+len(slist)]:
      return True
  return False

def main():
    test_list = ["a",9,1,3.14,2]
    original_list = ["a",1,"a",9,1,3.14,2]

    if sublist(test_list,original_list):
        print("It is a sublist!")
    else:
        print("It ain't a sublist!")

main()
```

**Output**

```
It is a sublist!
```

**Explanation**

Code:

```
for n in range(len(blist)-len(slist)+1):
```

> ```
> # We're looking for a starting index between
> # 0 and len(blist)-len(slist)
> # The reason it can be at most 
> # len(blist)-len(list) 
> # is that's the max index that still could 
> # have len(slist) elements
> # range(len(blist)-len(slist)+1) provides
> # numbers from 0 to en(blist)-len(slist)
> ```

```
   if slist == blist[n:n+len(slist)]:
```

> ```
>  # Check if we have a match from n to
>  # n + len(slist) - 1 (i.e. since slice
>  # a:b means index of elements from a to b-1
> ```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the code in lines 2 - and 3?

Comment: @MohamedTlili--added explanation.  Let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
def sublist(l2, l1):
    for i in range(0, len(l2) - len(l1) + 1):
        if l2[i] == l1[0]:
            for j in range(1, len(l1)):
                if l2[i + j] != l1[j]:
                    break
            else:
                return True
    return False


l1 = [3,3,10,4,9]
l2 = [3,10,4]

sublist(l1, l2)
# True
```

Comment: I really only want to use loops and boolean logic, not built-in functions.

Comment: @MohamedTlili check now my answer, I hope is better

Comment: You check only that all of l1 are in l2, they can be non-continuous and it wouldn't be a sublist

Comment: @azro forget to mention that the sublist has to be continuous. For example [3,9,8] is not a sublist of [2,3,1,9,7,8]

Comment: @MohamedTlili ok, now is for sure better

Comment: @kederrac Well yes, but my question was why my code isn't working.